# Why sharedPreferences.getString may return null?

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences

1) In the bellow picture I want to understand why **sharedPreferences.getString()** give me type mismatch that it may return null but **sharedPreferences.getBoolean()** and **sharedPreferences.getInt()** doesn't give me type mismatch warning?

2) What about defValue, doesn't it main that if it didn't find **SharedPrefKey.App_LANGUAGE** it will return **en**? so it can't return null, wright?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the implementation for `getString` in the `SharedPreferences` interface.

```
@Nullable
String getString(String key, @Nullable String defValue);
```

The method itself is marked as `@Nullable` which means that it can return null. Now if you look at the `defValue` parameter, you'll notice it's also marked as `@Nullable` meaning you don't have to pass in a default. If it's the case that you're looking for a string preference that doesn't exist and don't pass in a default value, then that will return null.

```
int getInt(String key, int defValue);
boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue);
```

If you look at the implementation of `getInt` and `getBoolean` above, you can tell that you *have* to pass in a default value, so it will never be null. This is why you see the difference in nullability with the examples you posted.

Comment: I think the fact that it's Java and `String` type means it can return `null`. The `@Nullable` annotation is a helper for IDEs mostly. With or without the annotation it could return `null`.

Comment: Yea but without the annotation, Kotlin doesn't know that. If you take away the annotation, then it would return a platform type `String!` and Kotlin wouldn't treat it as nullable. So you wouldn't get that error. It would however, crash if it did return null

Comment: Agree, but `String!` can still be `null`. I think it's kind of silly for Kotlin to assume `String!` a more correct assumption would have been `String?` That would allow the IDE to help you write safe calls into Java.

Comment: Yes, but the question was why he was getting the type mismatch error. If it wasn't marked with `@Nullable`, there would be no compile time error. There would only be a runtime error in the case where the `String!` value came back `null`

Comment: If a default argument to `getString` is provided, why would it still be nullable?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's calling Java code that can return a String, or null. For the `getBoolean()` function the value can only be true or false. You can't stuff null into `boolean` field.
2. Correct, you're defining a default value incase it can't find anything. You could also put `null` in the second parameter and it would be the same as without the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the possibility of null with something like this (Kotlin)

```
val string =sharedpreferences.getString(key, "default value") ?: "default value"
```